# Repetitive sequence constructor

Tags: c++

Can I build a

```
vector<vector<int> >
```

using Repetitive sequence constructor?

I know I can build one like

```
vector<int> v(10, 0);
```

but I dont know how to build a vector of vector using this same method. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it a vector as the second parameter:

```
// 10 x 10 elements, all initialized to 0
vector<vector<int> > v(10, vector<int>(10, 0));
```

Answer (score 4):

`vector<vector<int> > v(10, vector<int>(30, 0));` would create ten vectors with 30 zeroes each.

Answer (score 0):

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

***Repetitive sequence constructor:***  Initializes the vector with its content set to a repetition, `n` times, of copies of `value`.

```
vector< vector<int> > vI2Matrix(3, vector<int>(2,0));
```

Creates 3 vectors with 2 zeroes each.

Essentially, one would use vector of vectors for representing a two dimensional array.

Here is an source code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

main()
{
   // Declare size of two dimensional array and initialize.
   vector< vector<int> > vI2Matrix(3, vector<int>(2,0));    

   vI2Matrix[0][0] = 0;
   vI2Matrix[0][1] = 1;
   vI2Matrix[1][0] = 10;
   vI2Matrix[1][1] = 11;
   vI2Matrix[2][0] = 20;
   vI2Matrix[2][1] = 21;

   cout << "Loop by index:" << endl;

   int ii, jj;
   for(ii=0; ii < 3; ii++)
   {
      for(jj=0; jj < 2; jj++)
      {
         cout << vI2Matrix[ii][jj] << endl;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```